# Knockout Validation Need the Element

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I want to pass an entire element into my validation.

Element:

```
<input id="txtPhoneNumber" data-bind="value: Phone, intlTelInput: Phone" name="phone" type="text" class="form-control">
```

JS KO:

```
            ko.validation.rules['validPhone'] = {
              validator: function (val) {
                return val.intlTelInput('isValidNumber');
              },
              message: 'Invalid Phone Number'
            }
```

The problem I have is I don't want to rewrite intlTelInput which takes a element not just a straight value. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need access to the element? There's no real need for you to do so. Frankly, it's not something you should do, it limits the usability of your validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't approve in passing element to knockout validations but if you would really like to do that then you can make a custom binding that would pass the observable to be validated then from that custom binding you can already extend the observable to a validator and pass the element to it.

1.. Make the validator

```
`ko.validation.rules['validPhone'] = {
    validator: function (val, element) {
        //do what you want with the element here
        return val.intlTelInput('isValidNumber');
    },
    message: 'Invalid Phone Number'
}`
```

2.. Make the custom binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.validPhone = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor){
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable.extend({validPhone: element}) 
    }
}
```

3.. Element should be defined like this

```
<input id="txtPhoneNumber" data-bind="value: Phone, validPhone: Phone, intlTelInput: Phone" name="phone" type="text" class="form-control" >
```